# Get UTC offset in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, timezone, utc

Does anyone know the best way to get the UTC offset in WP7? Apparently the TimeZone api hasn't been implemented there.

Thanks

Comment: Use the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) structure, that's what it is for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `DateTimeOffset.Now.Offset`... that is why [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) was created!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to convert to local time, use `DateTime.ToLocalTime()`.  If you want the offset, I think you can subtract the original value.  [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like the below; this was done quickly but it works. In my case I always wanted time as of eastern time zone since that is where the event my app was for. Stored as UTC and calculated offset.

```
    private DateTime _startTimeUtc;
    private DateTime _startTime;

    public DateTime StartTime
    {
        get { return _startTime; }
        set
        {
            _startTimeUtc = value.ToUniversalTime();
            _startTime = _startTimeUtc.Subtract(EasternTimeUtcOffSet);
        }
    }

    public DateTime StartTimeUtc 
    {
        get { return _startTimeUtc; }

        set
        {
            _startTimeUtc = value;
            _startTime = _startTimeUtc.Subtract(EasternTimeUtcOffSet);
        }
    }

    private static TimeSpan EasternTimeUtcOffSet
    {
        get { return TimeSpan.FromHours(4); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private int TimeZoneOffset()
  {
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
      return dt.Subtract(dt.ToUniversalTime()).Hours;
  }
```