# How do I get the timezone offset in minutes on WP7?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, windows-phone-7, timezone

I need to be able to know what the timezone offset is for the device running my app in minutes. For example, for Pacific standard time (where I am testing), I need to get the int -480. Examples (which I should not be able to get from my current location - but to give you an idea of what I need) in Afghanistan I would get 270 and the UK is where I would get 0.

My best attempts so far have all returned 0 instead, which is the wrong value:

```
int timezoneOffsetInMinutes = (DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() - DateTime.Now).Minutes// returns 0 instead of the expected -480
```

and

```
int timezoneOffsetInMinutes = TimeZoneInfo.Utc.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes - TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset.Minutes;// also returns 0, not -480
```

I wasn't sure if [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182017/get-utc-offset-in-wp7) was asking the same question (as no example offsets or example code is given), but the one answer that is given there is definitely unrelated to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the *base/standard* offset, then [`TimeZoneInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396389%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is probably the most correct way of accessing that information (and also gives you access to other information, such as whether the timezone supports daylight savings time):

```
TimeSpan offset = TimeZoneInfo.Local.BaseUtcOffset;
```

However, if you want the *current* offset (including DST changes), I'd get into the habit of using [`DateTimeOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), as it has basically superceded `DateTime` (it's able represent a "local" time to a timezone that is different to the local machine's):

```
TimeSpan offset = DateTimeOffset.Now.Offet;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime utc = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
DateTime local = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan diff = (utc - local);
```

This returns the correct time difference between you and UTC.

Comment: This is progress - I'm getting the value 56 (not 0, for the first time). What is it that I don't understand about UTC that I'm not getting what I expect? My device and the emulator are both set to PST and they both get the same values

Comment: Ok, I see what I needed was diff.TotalMinutes (instead of just diff.Minutes). I'm still getting an off value (-419.999999 instead of the even -480 I expected). If anyone can tell me what is going on here, it would be appreciated. It doesn't really make sense to have a timezone offset that doesn't match what displays on the clock - that is no one on the west coast has there clock set to 6.99 hours behind greenwich time. Maybe this is a product of daylight savings time?